# Applications of finite Bolyai-Lobachevsky planes

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, coding-theory, finite-geometry

Google scholar gives more than 200 articles comcerning finite Bolyai-Lobachevsky (**BL**) planes. Usually they devoted to construction of such objects (axioms may be different).

> Are their any applications of these objects in combinatorics, coding theory etc?

I know one example: [Kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem). But it is slightly artificial because it can be solved using projective geometry of three dimensions over $GF(2)$.

The following axioms are taken from [The Existence of Finite Bolyai-Lobachevsky Planes](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2688738?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Steven H. Heath.

*Axiom 1.* If $P$ and $Q$ are two points there is exactly one line containing $P$
 and $Q$.

*Axiom 2.* If $l$ is any line there is a point $P$ which does not lie on $l$.

*Axiom 3.* There are at least two points on every line.

*Axiom 4.* There exists at least one line.

*Axiom 5.* Given a point $P$ not on a line $l$, there are exactly $k$ lines which are
 parallel to $l$ and pass through $P$.

A finite BL space satisfying Axioms 1-5 will be denoted by 
 $BL(k, n)$.

For example  $3$-dimensional finite projective geometry with $3$ points on each line 
is $BL(4,3)$. It leads to a solution of the Kirkman's Fifteen School
 Girl Problem. And any solution of this problem is a $BL (4, 3)$.